# UICollectionView paging via cell width

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I want to make paging in collection view not by collection view width, but by collection view cell width.

As shown in image. After paging in collection view, I want to align current cell at the left side of screen and keep left side of next cell visible (as shown in image). As I know I can use `ScrollViewWillEndDragging`, but I can't set it properly.

[image]

Comment: you can use CRRefresh https://github.com/CRAnimation/CRRefresh

Comment: Maziar, thank you for answer, but I don't think this is correct solution. I need something that will manage scrolling of paging position, not the animation of scrolling

Comment: this is not an animation, it has its own animator. this is a pull to refresh and load more component and it is RX listener on scroll.

Comment: this link maybe helps you:
https://dzone.com/articles/ios-swift-uicollectionview-with-horizontal-paginat